# window.captureEvents (Event.UNLOAD) open a new window

Tags: javascript

When I close or exit the page, at the same time a new window will be opened

```
window.captureEvents (Event.UNLOAD) 
window.onunload = page_click;

function page_click() {
    alert('page unload event detected!');
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:**

```
window.onunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.returnValue){
        window.open('http://google.com', 'name'); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Try this update :). It will open new tab if current window is closed.